# VB.NET MS Word - How to store a ms word table cell corresponding to a FOUND word.range into a table.Cell variable

Tags: vb.net, ms-word, vsto

I am trying to find a string in my word document header table. I can find the range but I want to store the specific cell which this found range is located in into a table.cell variable.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please clarify - are you trying to get the cell row/column address, index #, or its contents. If the latter, be aware that the contents include an end-of-cell marker - which is not the same as a paragraph break.

Comment: @macropod Thank you for you attention to my question. I am trying to store this cell's position (which in this case it maybe it's index) in my table which is located in my document's header. It seems that working with tables in word headers are not as easy as tables in document body.

Answer (score 0):

In VBA, for example, to retrieve the cell's table#, row # & column #:

```
Sub GetCellRef()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Rng As Range, t As Long, r As Long, c As Long
With ActiveDocument.Sections.First.Headers(wdHeaderFooterPrimary)
  Set Rng = .Range
  With .Range
    With .Find
      .Text = "Text to Find"
      .Forward = True
      .Wrap = wdFindStop
      .MatchCase = False
      .MatchWholeWord = True
      .Execute
    End With
    If .Find.Found = True Then
      If .Information(wdWithInTable) = True Then
        Rng.End = .Cells(1).Range.End - 1
        t = Rng.Tables.Count
        Rng.Start = .Start
        r = .Cells(1).RowIndex
        c = .Cells(1).ColumnIndex
        MsgBox Chr(34) & Rng.Text & Chr(34) & vbCr & _
        "Found in table " & t & " at row " & r & " column " & c
      End If
    End If
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```